# How to change the breakpoints of Rebass?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, emotion, rebass

I'm trying to change the default breakpoints, but it's not working. I followed the docs and used `ThemeProvider`, but Rebass is still using the default breakpoints. Instead of using `emotion-theming`, I use `@emotion/react` because of this error:

```sh
Error: `emotion-theming` has been removed and all its exports were moved to `@emotion/react` package
```

I use these versions:

```json
"@emotion/react": "^11.1.5",
"rebass": "^4.0.7"
```

#### My Code

**_app.js**

```
import { ThemeProvider } from "@emotion/react";

const theme = {
  breakpoints: ["768px", "1024px"]
};

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

**index.js**

```
import { Box, Flex } from "rebass";

export default function IndexPage() {
  return (
    <Flex sx={{ flexDirection: ["column", "column", "row"] }}>
      <Box sx={{ width: ["100%", "100%", "50%"], marginBottom: [10, 25, 0] }}>
        Hello
      </Box>
      <Box sx={{ width: ["100%", "100%", "50%"] }}>World</Box>
    </Flex>
  );
}
```

#### CodeSandbox

I've also created a sandbox for reproduction: https://codesandbox.io/s/rebass-themeprovider-wcc6b

#### Expectations

The breakpoints should be `768px` and `1024px` instead of `40em` and `52em`.

Comment: Rebass is not up to date with the latest emotion, that's why it's not working

Comment: @simplecreator is there a solution? I can't use the `emotion-theming` because it gives an Internal Server Error...

Comment: I've just copied the source code of Flex and Box components. I wouldn't recommend using Rebass itself anymore because of the lack of updates.